# MVC 3 Display HTML inside a ValidationSummary

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to display a strong tag inside a validation summary but it encodes it and does not display properly.

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "<strong>ERROR:<strong>The form is not valid!")
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could extend the ValidationSummary helper as has been suggested in the accepted answer on  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918969/how-to-extend-the-validationsummary-html-helper-in-asp-net-mvc).

Edit: I presume the encoding of any text entered is a security feature and therefore a good thing.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. See below correct answer by @ra. This answer only shows a good way of using ValidationSummary. But not how to show html in ValidationSummary.

Answer (score 39):

The easiest way:

```
@if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
<div>@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.ValidationSummary(false, "<strong>ERROR:<strong>The form is not valid!").ToHtmlString()))</div>
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode((Html.ValidationSummary(false) ?? (object)"").ToString()))
```

Answer (score 6):

I've find this :

```
    public static MvcHtmlString ToMvcHtmlString(this MvcHtmlString htmlString)
    {
        if (htmlString != null)
        {
            return new MvcHtmlString(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(htmlString.ToString()));
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and then :

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "<strong>ERROR:<strong>The form is not valid!").ToMvcHtmlString()
```

Answer (score -4):

I have a site that uses Resource files for language. In one of the items I placed this for the Value: `<img src="images/exclamation.png" > <strong>Pharmacy Name is required</strong>` and it works.