# C# MVC Razor Html.ValidationSummary show message as HTML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, validationsummary

I want to show the validation summary as HTML format, for example.

Code behind (controller):

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "Account not confirmed<br />Click <a href='#'>here</a> to resend the email confirmation");
```

Razor View:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" });
```

An the rendered HTML is like:

```
Account not confirmed<br />Click <a href='#'>here</a> to resend the email confirmation
```

I mean, the html message is shown as it, but I want it to show with HTML tags.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005966/mvc-3-display-html-inside-a-validationsummary

Comment: You cannot. `@Html.ValidationSummary()` encodes the value. You need to create your own html (and validation messages are for displaying errors, not for displaying instructions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your time ... I found what I need:

[Render HTML in a Validation Message in ASP.NET MVC](http://jdav.is/2013/12/12/render-html-in-a-validation-message-in-asp-net-mvc/)

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own ValidationSummary,
Create a partial and named it _MyValidationSummary.cshtml

```
@model ModelStateDictionary
@if(!Model.IsValid)
{
    <div class="validation-summary-errors">
        <p>
            "Account not confirmed<br />
            Click <a href='#'>here</a> to resend the email confirmation"
        </p>
        <ul>
            //Errors
        </ul>
    </div>
}
```

Refer to it:

```
@Html.Partial("_MyValidationSummary", ViewData.ModelState);
```