# MVC3 - How to insert a ValidationMessageFor with a line break <br /> at the end?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm validating about 10 input fileds in a form. The ValidationMessageFor-tags should be at the top of the page, so I'm writing every one like:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customer.ADDRESS.NAME)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customer.ADDRESS.CITY)
```

and so on.
My Models look like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = Constants.ErrorMsgNameMissing)]
public string NAME { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = Constants.ErrorMsgCityMissing)]
public string CITY { get; set; }
```

The constants are Strings.
Now, if more than one ValidationMessageFor is shown, they are all in one line.
How can I insert a line break like `<br />` at the end of every message?

This is NOT the right way:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customer.ADDRESS.NAME)<br />
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customer.ADDRESS.CITY)<br />
```

since the `<br />` is shown even if there is no error...;)

Thanks in advance.

PS: Displaying them as a list would also be great.

Comment: Any particular reason why `@Html.ValidationSummary()` will not suffice?

Comment: Nope...damn. That was too easy :p Write it in an answer and I will accept that...oh man. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're actually looking for is:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with **@Html.ValidationSummary()** if possible

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Custom ValidationSummary template Asp.net MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857851/custom-validationsummary-template-asp-net-mvc-3).  I think it would be best for your situation if you had complete control over how the validation is rendered.  You could easily write an extension method for `ValidationMessageFor`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, at the top should be:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(/*...*/)
```

The field validations should be with their respective fields.

However, if you absolutely insist on putting `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(/*...*/)` at the top then adjust their layout behavior in your CSS and forget about the `<br />`'s

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a built in way, but you could easily make another Extension method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ValidationMessageLineFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression) {
    return helper.ValidationMessageFor(expression) + "<br />";
}
```

Something like that?