# Show only first error message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling, validation

I am using ASP.NET MVC3 for a form that has both server and client validations. I'm showing error messages as balloons above the inputs. Due to the presentation of the errors, I need to only show one error at a time, otherwise the balloons tend to obscure other fields that may also be in error.

How can I customize the validation behavior to only render the first error message?

Edit: Please notice that the form has both server and client validations, and that I only want to show the first error message for the entire form (not per field).

Comment: This is more of a presentation issue, can you handle it with css?

Comment: Will showing one error at a time frustrate the users?

Comment: @Rob A: The only feasible CSS solution would be via first/nth-of-type, but this is not supported in IE8 and below.

Comment: @Mark: I don't think so. Errors are the exception when filling out a form, so there will typically only be one or two. Btw... this is exactly how it works in Apple's checkout process, which I think remains quite user friendly while being fairly sophisticated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone needs it, the solution I came up with is to add the following script towards the bottom of the page. This hooks into the existing javascript validation to dynamically hide all but the first error in the form.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var form = $('form')[0];
        var settings = $.data(form, 'validator').settings;
        var errorPlacementFunction = settings.errorPlacement;
        var successFunction = settings.success;

        settings.errorPlacement = function(error, inputElement) {
            errorPlacementFunction(error, inputElement);
            showOneError();
        }
        settings.success = function (error) {
            successFunction(error);
            showOneError();
        }
        function showOneError() {
            var $errors = $(form).find(".field-validation-error");
            $errors.slice(1).hide();
            $errors.filter(":first:not(:visible)").show();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sadly this didn't work for me, none of the methods seem to trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Could give this a shot on your controller action

```
var goodErrors = ModelState.GroupBy(MS => MS.Key).Select(ms => ms.First()).ToDictionary(ms => ms.Key, ms => ms.Value);
ModelState.Clear();

foreach (var item in goodErrors)
{
    ModelState.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

I'm just selecting only one of each property error, clearing all errors then adding the individual ones back.

this is completely untested but should work.

Comment: I just want to clarify that it is the first error in the form that I want to show, rather than the first error per field. I did adapt your approach to test this, but the problem is that it doesn't address client side validations.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom validation summary which would display only the first error. This could be done either by creating an extension for the HtmlHelper class, or by writing your own HtmlHelper. The former is the more straightforward.

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    static string SingleMessageValidationSummary(this HtmlHelper helper, string validationMessage="") 
    {
        string retVal = "";
        if (helper.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
            return "";
        retVal += @"<div class=""notification-warnings""><span>";
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(validationMessage))
            retVal += validationMessage;
        retVal += "</span>";
        retVal += @"<div class=""text"">";
        foreach (var key in helper.ViewData.ModelState.Keys) 
        {
            foreach(var err in helper.ViewData.ModelState[key].Errors)
            retVal += "<p>" + err.ErrorMessage + "</p>";
            break;
        }
        retVal += "</div></div>";
        return retVal.ToString();
    }
}
```

This is for the ValidationSummary, but the same can be done for `ValidationMessageFor`.

See: [Custom ValidationSummary template Asp.net MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857851/custom-validationsummary-template-asp-net-mvc-3)

### Edit: Client Side...

Update jquery.validate.unobstrusive.js. In particular the `onError` function, where it says `error.removeClass("input-validation-error").appendTo(container);`

Untested, but change that line to: `error.removeClass("input-validation-error").eq(0).appendTo(container);`

Comment: I don't think this will address the client side validations though.

Comment: In that case you need to update jquery.validate.unobstrusive.js.

Comment: This seems like a much better approach.

Comment: I reviewed the suggested modification to jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js, but it seems that this will only set the first error per field, rather than the first error for the entire form.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `html helper extension` that renders only one message.

```
public static MvcHtmlString ValidationError(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
  var result = new StringBuilder();
  var tag = new TagBuilder("div");
  tag.AddCssClass("validation-summary-errors");

  var firstError = helper.ViewData.ModelState.SelectMany(k => k.Value.Errors).FirstOrDefault();

  if (firstError != null)
  {
    tag.InnerHtml = firstError.ErrorMessage;
  }

  result.Append(tag.ToString());
  return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());
}
```

Update the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` `OnErrors` function as below,

```
function onErrors(form, validator) {  // 'this' is the form element
   // newly added condition 
   if ($(form.currentTarget).hasClass("one-error")) {
      var container = $(this).find(".validation-summary-errors");
      var firstError = validator.errorList[0];

      $(container).html(firstError.message);
    }
    else {
      var container = $(this).find("[data-valmsg-summary=true]"),
            list = container.find("ul");

      if (list && list.length && validator.errorList.length) {
        list.empty();
        container.addClass("validation-summary-errors").removeClass("validation-summary-valid");

        $.each(validator.errorList, function () {
          $("<li />").html(this.message).appendTo(list);
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Basically we have added a condition in the `OnError` to check whether the form contains a css-class named `one-error` and if yes then displays a single error else display all.