# How to display only one error message using Html.ValidationSummary?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, validation

I have a view (skipping redundant code for simplicity):

```
@model CompetencyModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Results)
}
```

When I submit, if validation fails inside `EditorFor`, ValidationSummary **shows the list of all validation messages** for each item coming from `EditorFor`.

This screenshot is a view, where `EditorFor` is a single line with radio buttons:

[image]

But I need a **single error message** just saying that something failed. I tried:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Results)
```

But it doesn't show anything. I tried

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Results)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Results, "ERROR !!!")
```

But it doesn't show anything.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

**Solution**
This will do the trick.

```
<style>.validation-summary-errors ul { display: none; }</style>
@Html.ValidationSummary("Can't save, you must answer all questions !!")
```

Comment: @Html.ValidationSummary(true) should work.  Is your form in a loop, by any chance?

Comment: Nope. If it shows a list of validation messages, it should show a general error message for EditorFor, if I pass (true), but it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ValidationExtensions.ValidationSummary method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460185%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) will always return an un-ordered list of items.

Another person asked this question and choose to use JQuery to hide the items: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10837702/1220302

Another solution you could do is only display the first item in the list using CSS's [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo tag. This of course is dependent on the browser version you're using though:

I think something like this:

```
.validation-summary-errors ul li:nth-child(-n+1) {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: i stand corrected. Summary returns ul or nothing as you said.

Comment: But what about: ValidationSummary(HtmlHelper helper, Boolean excludePropertyErrors, String message)??

excludePropertyErrors: true to have the summary display model-level errors only, or false to have the summary display all errors.

message: The message to display with the validation summary.

Comment: Oh, it seems this message only shows when the first parameter is false, like a lable for UL list of messages....

Comment: Yes, you are correct. If you don't already have it defined, you'll want to check out the IValidateable Interface if you're looking at doing a model-level validation summary.: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.server.ivalidatable(v=vs.90).aspx. On the validation topic, check out Fluent Validation as well. http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the following rule to hide all messages except the first:

```
.validation-summary-errors ul li:nth-child(n+2) {
    display:none;
}
```