# Custom Html.ValidationSummary()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm having problems the default Html.ValidationSummary() in MVC 3.

As default it adds this code:

```
<ul>
  <li style="display:none"></li>
</ul>
```

And that empty `<ul>` causes space I would like to get rid of.

Is there some way to work around this problem? Make it toggle some `div` around it or similar?

Comment: I guess this post may help you http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/9/simplifying_html_generation_using_razor_templates

Comment: Great post, and the others too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own validation summary, for example, like here: [Custom ValidationSummary template Asp.net MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857851/custom-validationsummary-template-asp-net-mvc-3)

Answer (score 8):

how about conditionally showing ValidationSummary

```
if(!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
 {
     @Html.ValidationSummary() 
 }
```

**important** if you do this you won't be able to use [client-side javascript validation](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html) (as the div wont be present)