# How can I check for text that will display with @Html.ValidationSummary() and then modify a message?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using `@Html.ValidationSummary()` on my registration page. If the user name entered is already used I get the following message HTML:

```
<div class="validation-summary-errors" data-valmsg-summary="true">
   <ul>
      <li>User name already exists. Please enter a different user name.</li>
   </ul>
```

What I would like is to be able to modify this message with a few lines of HTML so that if the message is exactly the same as the above then I will add on some HTML that shows a link to login. Something like this:

```
<div class="validation-summary-errors" data-valmsg-summary="true">
   <ul>
      <li>User name already exists. Please enter a different user name or <a xxxx>Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I tried to do something like the following:

```
@{
   var errorHTML = @Html.ValidationSummary();
   if ( errorHTML.IndexOf("User name already exists") > 0  ) {
        errorHTML = errorHTML + "xx"
   }                    
}
```

However I straight away came into a problem where it tells me that MvsHtmlString does not contain a definition of IndexOf.

Can someone suggest a way that I could check to see if there will be a validation message saying the user name already exists and then add some HTML and have that show up on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

One way to control the error message that is show for validation errors is to use the ModelState.AddModelError() method

`ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "User name already exists. Please enter a different user name or a xxxx");`

`@When Html.ValidationSummary()` is executed, the above message will be shown.

However, I don't know how the current message is being included in the summary, and whether you have control over that. In other words, where is that message coming from?

Comment: You have a good point I found the same error message comes from a view places in my MVC code: ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "User name already exists. Please enter a different user name.");  I am just thinking that rather than change it at source then maybe it would be best to check for it and modify it at the point of the view. What do you think?

Comment: I highly recommend changing the message at the source (in the view), it will be much less confusing that way.

Comment: But the source is my ASP MVC controllers and not the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your custom validation summary. Then use `Html.ValidationSummary()` to get MvcHtmlString and change the message.
Here are a couple of useful link on how to create customized validation summary extension:
[Custom ValidationSummary template Asp.net MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857851/custom-validationsummary-template-asp-net-mvc-3)
[How to extend the ValidationSummary HTML Helper in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918969/how-to-extend-the-validationsummary-html-helper-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: But do you think it's good to change it. I am still thinking it might make more sense to change at the one point where I need to change it which is just for a couple of views. If I could check for it in the razor code it might be a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You could write an Action Filter that will inspect the ModelState for an entry matching what you are looking for, then either modify it or remove it. Then you could decorate only the actions you want with the filter:

```
[RemoveModelStateEntry(MatchOn = "Username already exists.")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

When the action is executed and before it is presented, you could check the model state:

```
public class RemoveModelStateEntryAttribute : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        // check filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState here
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // nothing to do here
    }
}
```