# Change text of ValidationSummary C# razor MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, validationsummary

I am using `ValidationSummary` to show errors after submit login action on my login page.

There are two different errors to show.

> 1) Username and password invalid

or

> 2) You are not allowed to access this feature

The thing is that I want to change the text of the `ValidationSummary`. I don't want to add errors as bullet points (this is done adding errors to `ModelState` using `ModelState.AddModelError`).

How can I achieve this? Change the error message of the `ValidationSummary`?

Thanks!

Comment: so do you want to show either error msg 1 or 2?

Comment: or show both but not as bullet points?

Comment: Seems that your best option is a separate validation message. Something like "if whole thing not valid show this message". Or refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/918969/728795

Comment: @AmrElgarhy I want to show error msg 1 or error msg 2, not both! And I dont want to add them on ModelState because that will use bullet points

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is that you can return message in json in your post method. and display that message in span instead of validation summary.

For example

```
return Json(new object[] { false, "Invalid user name or password" }, 
                           JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: That's too much for showing a error message, I would want to maintain the signature of my method, but thanks